A few doubts regarding the geometry and representations of spacetime diagrams
I had a couple questions regarding the geometry of space-time diagrams, and I believe that this specific example in Hartle's book will help me understand.

However, I am unable to wrap my head around a few things:

In the example we see that the slope of the light cones $\frac{dT}{dX} = \pm \frac{1}{X}$ should depend only on the co-ordinate X. In the figure, I'm assuming the dotted lines trace out the slope of the cones at different points. Since the slope only depends on X, shouldn't the curves run parallel to each other? That is, shouldn't points on the same vertical line have the same slope?
Towards the end of the example, the author mentions that the given metric is in fact the flat space-time metric, then shouldn't the light cones look the same at all points regardless of what co-ordinate system is used? Is this metric truly for flat spacetime? I couldn't find any transformations that could bring me back to the standard form


Please narrow this down to a single question.

@VincentThacker can both my doubts be addressed through a single question. If so, I don't how to phrase them. If not, I didn't see any rule saying a single question per post and I'd like to avoid duplicating a post just to ask a related question.


The dotted lines are null trajectories. You are correct there is no $T$-dependence in the slope of the light cones. Therefore, the slope of all dotted lines along a vertical (of constant $X$) is the same. I've sketched this below.



Consider the following coordinate transformation

\begin{cases}
t = X\,\sinh T \\
x = X\,\cosh T \\
\end{cases}
This recovers the usual Minkowski line element:
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = -X^2 dT^2 + dX^2 = -dt^2 + dx^2
\end{equation}
The example illustrates that light cones are dependent on the coordinate system used, even in flat space. For a more complete discussion, see Rindler coordinates.

thank you for the sketch. It does look like the slope is the same for a given vertical, doesn't it? But then why do the lines appear to converge on the top right and diverge on the bottom left? Is this just a diagrammatic inaccuracy?

@amansas It's not an inaccuracy. It's just the nature of the null curves in this coordinate system. You can integrate $dT/dX = \pm 1/X$ to obtain $T(X) = \pm\ln{X} + C$ for some integration constant $C$. Notice these all have the same slope ($1/X$), but different "offsets" due to the integration constant. $\pm\ln{X}\rightarrow\pm\infty$ as $X\rightarrow 0$ which is the divergence you are seeing.
